# Converting a string to a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

I have a nested for loop that creates a empty string value that represents a multidimensional array. Once the for loops have finished the result is something like this:

```
"[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]"
```

I would like to add this to a multidimensional array within my code, how would i do this?

I have tried:

```
map = eval("[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]");
```

but this does not produce the correct multidimensional array i am looking for.

I am looking to be able to use the array like this:

```
map[0][1] == 1;
```

Thanks

Comment: where you you expect the right hand side `1` to come from?

Comment: What produces the initial string? What is consuming it? Have you worked with JSON before?

Comment: `JSON.parse()` will return the array as you want it.  But why is it a string in the first place if you generated it in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the string using `JSON.parse()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)).

```
var str = "[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]";

var map = JSON.parse( str );
```

However, in your example there is no entry equaling `1`, so you requirement `map[0][1] == 1` wont be fulfilled that way.

Comment: I realise that there is no 1 in the array shown. I just made that string up to give an example of what it will look like. And thank you for the example it worked perfectly!